# unable to find where to reduce the top space after frame title in latex beamer class

Tags: beamer, frame-title, frame

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, aspectratio=169, 11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}

\section{Components of Figure}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Components of Figure}

     \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Img/components_of_graphs.png}
     \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As there are two many packages and I am unable to understand those so gave a smaller one

Comment: It seems that your image is to tall that can be nicely positioned in frame. Try to define image height, for example with `\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Img/components_of_graphs.png}`. BTW, in the `beamer`   the `figure` doesn't float, so the positioning option ˙[h]` is superfluous.

Comment: If above comment doesn't help, than your image may contain some white space above diagram. Too see this, insert it in `\fbox`:  `\fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{Img/components_of_graphs.png}}`.

Comment: Things I would try: (a) not use `\begin{figure}` because I am not numbering the figures; plus it might insert unwanted spaces. (b) insert a negative spaces like `\vspace*{-1cm}`. This always works.